# Why is max pooling preferred over average pooling in convolutional neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

In most CNN guides max pooling is explained and it is just mentioned that also average pooling exists. Why is max pooling preferred over average pooling? Average (or even median) seems to make more sense to me?

Comment: Look up translation invariance

Comment: @Firebug , sorry I don't get the connection ... What does taking the maximum value have to do with rotations? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208936/what-is-translation-invariance-in-computer-vision-and-convolutional-neural-netwo

Comment: It does not have anything to do with rotations specifically. I mentioned translation invariance